# hadoop: sqoop- why jdbc code is written in reducers?

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, mapreduce, sqoop

I am newbie to hadoop and its eco-systems. 
Sqoop : imports/exports data from/to hdfs - RDBMS. Sqoop compatible with JDBC related databases.

Why is that all the jdbc code written in reducers rather in mappers while importing and exporting the data from /to hdfs - RDBMS ? Some say to avoid Ddos (Distributed Denial of service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no reducers in Sqoop.Sqoop requires only mappers for import and export.For importing data from RDBMS to Hadoop Sqoop has input format which uses JDBC for getting data from databases.Similarly,sqoop has outputformats which are used to write data to RDBMS while exporting data form Hadoop